# Ruby On Rails ActiveRecord 3 Way Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 3 models:

```
class ProductLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specifications
  has_many :specification_categories, :through => :specifications,
end

class Specification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_line
  belongs_to :specification_category
end

class SpecificationCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specifications
  has_many :product_lines, :through => :specifications
end
```

Basically, we are showing the specifications as a subset of data on the product line page and we would like to do something like (example only, yes I'm aware of N+1):

Controller:

```
@product_line = ProductLine.find(params[:id])
@specification_categories = @product_line.specification_categories)
```

View:

```
@specification_categories.each do |specification_category|
 ...
 specification_category.specifications.each do |specification|
  ...
 end
end
```

The issue here is getting rails to filter the specifications by ProductLine.  I've tried constructing queries to do this but it always generates a separate NEW query when the final association is called.  Even though we aren't using the code above now (not a good idea here, since we could potentially run into an N+1 problem), I'd like to know if it's even possible to do a 3 way join with association filtering.  Has anyone run across this scenario?  Can you please provide an example of how I would accomplish this here?

Comment: Can you please share your log that shows the SQL statements. ActiveRecord tries hard to optimize database calls and sometimes used multiple calls where we would expect just one. Also, is your goal here to make just one database call, or to optimize the database access time?

Answer (score 0):

1. Prevent the N+1 by altering your line to:
   @specification_categories = @product_line.specification_categories).include(:specifications)

OR

1. Construct your own query using .joins(:association), and do the grouping yourself.

Comment: I don't have the N+1 issue, already fixed it.  I'm asking how to best do the grouping.  If i try to construct the query myself, it constructions a new query (select * from specifications.* where specification_category_id = 1) the second i call the association instead of utilizing my existing query.